# Does the series$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2+n!} $ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does the series $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^n}{n^2+n!} $   converge or diverge?

I tried using the ratio test but wasn't able to finish it

$$\frac{2(n^2+n!)}{(n+1)^2+(n+1)!}$$

Comment: $\frac{2^n}{n^2+n!}<\frac{2^n}{n!}$

Comment: Are you asking about the sequence $\frac{2^n}{n^2+n!}$ or the series with that term? You asked about the sequence, but then you used the ratio test, which is used for series.

Comment: sorry about that, it's the series with that term

Comment: Then you should edit your question.

Comment: i'm going to do it. i don't know how to use latex, so i'm searching here

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably, the easier way is to compare the series to $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^n}{n!}$ as zkutch comment suggest. But using the ratio test also works, just divide numerator and denominator by $n!$:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2(n^2+n!)}{(n+1)^2+(n+1)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{2(n^2/n!+1)}{(n+1)^2/n!+n+1} = 0$$

since the numerator tends to $2$ and the denominator tends to $\infty$.

This is a standard technique: when dealing with quotients of sums divide by the dominant term ($n!$ dominates $n^2$ by a lot).